# SOAP top level node missing

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-2010

I've imported a WSDL(using autoversion detect...), now when I attempt to use it I get an error similar to "top level node missing, Line: 0", I've spent a lot of hours on google to find a fix for this and I've seen that a lot of people have experienced same issue, however I couldn't find a fix for it.

I'm pretty sure a lot of you developers out there have fixed this issue, so my question is **HOW**?!

When imported the WSDL it generated the main interface which has helper methods and a special function which returns the main interface, example:

```
type
  array_of_string = array of string;
  ASpecialInterface = interface(IInvokable)
    //...
    function ASpecialMethod(const dummyArg: string): array_of_string; stdcall;
    //...
  end;
```

and a method which returns ASpecialInterface, example:

```
function GetASpecialInterface(const UseWSDL: Boolean; const addr: string; const ahttprio: THTTPRio): ASpecialInterface;
```

here is my issue:

```
procedure TMyForm.OnAButtonClick(Sender: Tobject);
var 
  LArrayOfString: array_of_string;
  LSpecialIntf: ASpecialInterface;
begin
  // this works without any issue whatsoever
  LSpecialIntf := GetASpecialInterface; // I call it with default params
  // the next code raises the exception mentioned above
  LArrayOfString := LSpecialIntf.ASpecialMethod(EmptyStr); // no param passed since the dummyArg is dummy
end;
```

Now, I'm not sure if this is valuable but the connection is made using SSL, i.e. https://domain.com/...

**EDIT: I'm sorry, forgot to mention that I'm using Delphi 2010**

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: What Delphi version do you use? In D2010 you get this error when the server is not found. https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=44545&tstart=0

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson sorry that I forgot to mention, I'm using Delphi 2010, I don't really think their server is down or whatever, however, I just pinged and it seems that it cannot find one of the addresses, that's really weird :-\

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson it seems that your answer is the correct one, post it as answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Delphi 2010 there is bug in soaphttptrans.pas. When the server for some reason is not found the exception you get is EDOMParseError instead of a ESOAPHTTPException, as it was before. More info can be found here: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=44545&tstart=0